# Have several different URLs direct to the same wordpress page with url parameters

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

What I am trying to do is redirect links like the following

`http://mydomain.com/library.1234/`

which would turn into this: `http://mydomain.com/wp_content/themes/my_theme/page-library.php?user_id=1234`

The wordpress page is called `Library` and the slug is `library` so I use the `page-library.php` file to customize the content in this page.

I want the page to dynamically generate content depending on the `user_id` that was passed in through that URL.

In the `page-library.php` can I simply use `$_GET['user_id']` to get the user_id from the link?

Also when a user uses the following url `http://mydomain.com/library.1234/` how can I ensure that this doesn't change in the address bar?

Is there a better way of doing this in wordpress?

Comment: You need to choose a different query variable name. `$_GET['user_id']` is a Wordpress variable and will have unintended side-effects.

Comment: okay, but would this implementation actually work?

Comment: It would work..... but I would argue that it wouldn't work well. The whole approach seems a little janky to me, and pretty much tries to circumvent Wordpress' existing functionality that does this for you. My advice? [Follow this guide](http://justintadlock.com/archives/2013/01/29/how-to-change-your-author-archive-link) to map your author links (mydomain.com/author/1234) to the library page, then add an .htaccess rule to understand `library.1234` as `library/1234`. That's where I'd start.

Comment: I think you misunderstood what I wanted. This library page will be custom generated depending on the user id. I basically want to show the user's libraries that they've created on the site. You don't need to worry about the internals of the `page-library.php` I just want a nice looking url that will give me the `user-id` of the user and use the `page-library.php` for handling the requests.

Comment: Oh! My bad. Then you should be ok. Still, if you haven't already, just create your Custom Post Type called "library". The /library root will serve as a general archive, and you can have your template exist as archive-library.php. You can then hook into pre_get_posts to modify your query in the event you have data in your custom $_GET request. You'll still need to create .htaccess rules for this, but overall, this makes a lot more sense to me now.